# Start tmux in choose-tree mode

Tags: tmux

When starting tmux, if I want to choose a session but am not sure which one, it would be really handy to launch tmux in the choose-tree mode, so that once I chose a session, it didn't leave a detached and empty one behind.

I found this asked on another site, and it has an answer.  But, the person who answered it deleted their account which took their answer with it.  I can see a comment to their (now empty) answer which said it involves a `;`.

My strong hope is from a bash script, being able to run `exec tmux (some arguments)` to get this to work.  I've already written a tmux starter script, and would like to add this to it.

Comment: what about just `tmux attach` and then you can choose (prefix+s) other session?

Comment: @Kent - Looks like that's the right track.  Just posted an answer that someone showed me how to resurrect of `tmux attach\; choose-tree`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently there's a website called removeddit.com that can show deleted comments/threads from Reddit.

Turns out this works:

```
tmux attach\; choose-tree
```

Or, for my specific case:

```
exec tmux attach\; choose-tree
```

There might be a better way, but this seems to work.

Escaping the `;` prevents bash from processing it, allowing tmux to use it.